# Why status bar disappear when I tap push notification and move ViewController in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    /* */
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = UIViewController()
    self.window?.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    /*

    fetch and add push notification data

     */
    goAnotherVC()
}

func goAnotherVC() {
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.active) {
        /* active stage is working */ 
    } else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.inactive || application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.background) {
        if (type == "1" || type == "2") {
            let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyAppointments", bundle: nil)
            let apptVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NotificationDetailViewController") as! NotificationDetailViewController
            let navigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: apptVC)
            self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        } else if (type == "3") {
            let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyAppointments", bundle: nil)
            let apptVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NotificationDetailViewController") as! NotificationDetailViewController
            let navigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: apptVC)
            self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        } else if (type == "4") {
            let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Enquiry", bundle: nil)
            let enqVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EnquiryDetailViewController") as! EnquiryDetailViewController
            let navigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: enqVC)
            self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
}
```

Above code is fetch push notification data and send to related View Controller when user tapped on it. But I've found that status bar is missing when View Controller is open. Please let me know how to fix it, thanks.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this setting by -prefersStatusBarHidden to NO

Comment: not working though

Answer (score 1):

At firs glance (and without actually verifying the code) my suspicion would be that the culprit is this:

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
```

You are setting your window to cover the full bounds of the view. To see if this is the issue, simply change that line to the following:

```
var rect = UIScreen.main.bounds
rect.origin.y += 20
self.window = UIWindow(frame: rect)
```

And see if the issue goes away. In my code, I've simply changed the top position of the window to allow for the status bar.

Comment: it look not good as taking more extra space as navigation bar its height is bigger than normal.